# AutoHotKey v2 - Comparing Strings Not Working

Tags: autohotkey

I am trying to do a string comparison in AHK v2 but its not working

```
F24::
{
    CoordMode "Mouse"
    Click 1145,175
    MouseGetPos &xpos,&ypos,&OutputVarWin,&OutputVarControl
    myText := WinGetText(OutputVarWin)

    if (myText = "GA")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's GA")
    }
    
    else if (myState = "FL")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's FL")
    }
}
```

when you press F24, it moves the mouse cursor to a specific coordinate.
it gets the ID of the control underneath it and gets the text from the box and saves it as myText

the text it puts into the myText variable is correct so no issue there

I then try to compare myText to a specific 2 letter state abbreviation but it won't get past the first if statement.

```
F24::
{
    CoordMode "Mouse"
    Click 1145,175
    MouseGetPos &xpos,&ypos,&OutputVarWin,&OutputVarControl
    myText := WinGetText(OutputVarWin)

    if (myText = "GA")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's GA")
    }
    
    else (myState = "FL")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's FL")
    }
}
```

if i change it to else (not else if), then it will automatically do whatever is in the brackets for the else

```
F24::
{
        stateGA := "GA"
        stateFL := "FL"
    CoordMode "Mouse"
    Click 1145,175
    MouseGetPos &xpos,&ypos,&OutputVarWin,&OutputVarControl
    myText := WinGetText(OutputVarWin)

    if (stateGA = "GA")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's GA")
    }
    
    else if (stateFL = "FL")
    {
        MsgBox ("it's FL")
    }
}
```

when i create variables internally and compare that to the two letter abbreviation, it works

is there something perhaps with HOW its comparing them? encoding? i'm totally lost here

Comment: When you say that `the text it puts into the myText variable is correct`, I'm assuming you mean you've tried logging out the contents of `myText` just before you run the comparison? Did you also make sure there are no preceding or trailing spaces?

Comment: funny you mention that, i did a StrLen() just now on what it was taking from the window and it returned 4 -- when i did the same StrLen() on a variable i made, it correctly returned 2

Comment: You can add `MsgBox "myText is '" myText "'"` to see the exact value of that variable.

Comment: You could also try `Trim(myText)` or even `Mid(myText,2,2)` if it is those pesky leading or trailing non-printing characters.

Answer (score 0):

Almost certainly it is those pesky non-printing characters confusing things.

Couple of ways to do this. In the variable:

```
myText := Trim(WinGetText(OutputVarWin))
```

or

```
myText := Mid(WinGetText(OutputVarWin),2,2) ; adjust first number
```

or in the conditional tests:

```
if Instr(myText,"GA")
```

etc.